# Cannot connect any bluetooth device on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 any Bluetooth device, I tried, connects and immediately disconnects again.
Do I have to adjust some setting/software to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out, where I can see the actual problem. It was becouse of a2dp-sink profile failure
[image]
The solution I found here [a2dp-sink profile connect failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172000/a2dp-sink-profile-connect-failed). The answer form Marko.

Comment: [ Share ] -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1228816/289138