# Audio not working as expected after ubuntu 22.10 upgrade

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 22.04, 22.10

I have not been able to get my audio to work as expected since I upgraded my ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

1. My Bluetooth earphones were not connecting. They would appear as available device and when I try to connect they connect and immediately disconnect and then I cannot switch on the device connection. I resolved this by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172000/a2dp-sink-profile-connect-failed/1228816#1228816)
2. Post this I had to do `pulseaudio --start` at every restart of the PC otherwise the Bluetooth connection could not be established again. I could establish the Bluetooth connections only post doing `pulseaudio --start`. I resolved this by going to Startup Applications Preferences. I could not find any pulseaudio application so I added one. Name - pulseaudio, command - pulseaudion --start [image]
3. Now my Bluetooth earphones connect [image] But the sound still comes from the the system speakers. In fact the Bluetooth earphones are not even listed under available devices. [image]. Also, when I put my earbuds back in the case the video that I am playing does pause. So my system is aware of the connected Bluetooth earphones on that level. Just cannot get the audio through them
4. `pulseaudio` command results in `E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running. E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.`
5. Followed the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481951/bluetooth-headset-connects-but-not-showing-in-sound-settings). `sudo -H pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` does not help
6. Have also run `rm  ~/.config/pulse/*` and restarted the system. Still no help

How can I use my Bluetooth earphones on my system. I am on a ThinkPad carbon x1 gen 7

Answer (score 4):

Firstly please be aware that Ubuntu 22.10 has replaced Pulseaudio with the newer Pipewire sound server.

You are suggesting to go back to Pulseaudio. This might work but I assume you will have other problems in the long run.

I did have the same problem, bluetooth audio did not work anymore. All the suggested checks did not show any problems, bluetooth was enabled, not blocked etc.

In the end I managed to still got bluetooth audio to work.

Install the libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - bluetooth plugins

`sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth`

after that I had to restart pipewire (or do a restart)

`systemctl --user restart pipewire`

sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/xjbqtg/no_bluetooth_audio_device_after_upgrade_to_2210/
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1339897/17250

Comment: Been searching for a solution for my bluetooth headphones for a while. This finally worked. Thanks a ton.