# Ubuntu 22.04 no sound on bluethoot headphones, but they show connected

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, headphones, sony

I have "LE_WH-1000XM4 Sony" headphones and I'm using a "PowerGuard USB Dongle Bluetooth 5.0 Receiver Transmitter Mini Adapter" Bluetooth adapter to connect my headphones to Ubuntu 22.04. They show up in the Bluetooth tab and connect, but they don't play any sound.

I tried the first two answers from this question: [No sound from bluetooth headset, but it's detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239209/no-sound-from-bluetooth-headset-but-its-detected), without success. Installing PulseAudio Volume Control did nothing for me and the a2dp.py script returns following error:

```
Connection MADE
Device MAC: CB:22:14:18:47:1E
Cannot find `bluez_card.CB_22_14_18_47_1E` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 15 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.CB_22_14_18_47_1E` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 14 more times
```

After trying 15 times it exits without success.
Any idea how I can get my headphones to work?

Comment: Did you try https://askubuntu.com/a/1228816/1004020 ?

Comment: I just tried it and that didn't work