# Bluetooth was working fine till yesterday in Ubuntu 22.04.4 but not now

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, asus

I did some troubleshooting by running a restart, checking the status of the Bluetooth, removing and reinstalling it, and whatnot.
But whatever I did the best I was able to do was to my headphones got connected but the sound was coming from the laptop speaker and not from the headphones.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-26 07:06:42 IST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4623 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8702)
     Memory: 768.0K
        CPU: 55ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4623 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 26 07:06:42 asus systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Starting SDP server
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 init>
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: src/adapter.c:reset_adv_monitors_complet>
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Failed to clear UUIDs: Failed (0x03)
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
Feb 26 07:06:42 asus bluetoothd[4623]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
```

This is the current status. Can anyone help me resolve this out? I am a new user of Ubuntu.
**Thanks**

Hi Daniel, Thanks for responding to the question. One thing that got correct after following your answer that I did not get any error in status check

```
[sudo] password for raghu: 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-26 20:17:45 IST; 4min 46s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 762 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8702)
     Memory: 2.2M
        CPU: 119ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─762 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -d

Feb 26 20:22:26 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout()
Feb 26 20:22:26 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout() a>
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0>
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:trigger_start_discovery()
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:cancel_passive_scanning()
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout()
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout() a>
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout() s>
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_complete() >
Feb 26 20:22:27 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0>
lines 1-22/22 (END)
```

Here is the full log of `journalctl -r -b -0 -u bluetooth`
you can have a look at it

```
Feb 26 20:19:56 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/device.c:device_set_legacy() legacy 0
Feb 26 20:19:56 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:device_found_callback() hci>
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0>
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_complete() >
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout() s>
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout() a>
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:start_discovery_timeout()
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:cancel_passive_scanning()
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:trigger_start_discovery()
Feb 26 20:19:51 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:discovering_callback() hci0>
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:cancel_passive_scanning()
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:trigger_start_discovery()
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() stat>
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bo>
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() >
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 1
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Feb 26 20:19:50 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 4>
Feb 26 20:19:49 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/device.c:device_set_rssi_with_delta()>
Feb 26 20:19:49 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/device.c:device_set_legacy() legacy 0
Feb 26 20:19:49 asus bluetoothd[762]: src/adapter.c:device_found_callback() hci>
```

Thanks once again.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is [caused by](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=291350) Bluetooth being disabled. Check for any hardware switches first. Then run the following to enable it:

```bash
rfkill unblock all
reboot
```

If you still see the error, we can reinstall BlueZ:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/bluetooth /etc/bluetooth
apt download bluez
sudo dpkg -P --force-all bluez
sudo dpkg -i ./bluez*.deb
```

That should reinstall BlueZ. If BlueZ is still broken, please add the `-d` flag to the `ExecStart` line in `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` , reboot, and attach the full log of `journalctl -r -b -0 -u bluetooth` .

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for responding to the qusetion.

Comment: I have edited the main question and added the log file as the problem is not yet solved. My headphones get connected by the sound is coming off through the laptop speaker.

Comment: @RaghuAnand For that problem, see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1432859/1004020